# how to add route inside android mapfragment?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google map in my app and i want to show route between two points.below are the latitudes and longitude.

```
    LatLng pune = new LatLng(18.6099, 73.8171);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pune).title("Marker in pune"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pune));
    mo.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

    LatLng mumbai = new LatLng(19.0829, 72.8831);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mumbai).title("Marker in mumbai"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mumbai));
    mo.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
```

Please help

Comment: try this link for [draw path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689271/make-route-of-public-transportation-in-google-maps?noredirect=1#comment57127252_34689271) on google map.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this tutorial for face your problem
http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/